Firefox opens as a different app in the Dock in 24.04
When Firefox is closed in Ubuntu 24.04, the Dock doesn't have the app with the gray gear icon (the one above the phone icon). It appears when I open Firefox and contains all the windows of Firefox I have open. How can I get it to use the actual Firefox I already have in the dock instead of it being recognized as a different app?
Dock with Firefox open:

Dock with Firefox closed:


I would be inclined to start over. Remove all instances of Firefox, decide which one you want to use and install that.

For Mozilla Firefox :
You need to locate the Firefox.desktop file and edit it with a text editor and change this line to look like this:
you might find it here : /snap/Firefox/current
StartupWMClass=firefox-release

Then save it and hopefully should work.
for Firefox Developer Edition:
You need to go to : .local/share/applications and edit the Firefox .desktop file with a text editor and set the StartupWMClass to this value like this:
StartupWMClass=firefox-aurora

and save the file, then hopefully it will work normally.

If Firefox was pre-installed, remove the Firefox app from the dock with a right mouse click and select Remove from Favourites.
Then open it using the Super key and typing the name of the in the search box. The icon will once again appear in the Dock.
Right mouse click and this time select 'Add to favourites' to pin it to the Dock once again.

I originally had the preinstalled one. It was lagging when I watched YouTube, so I swapped it for the apt version, but that only made the lag worse (Most likely due to it being an older version compared to the snap version) so I switched back. This only started after switching back. I followed this answer on another question to switch to the apt version, and followed the same answer to undo the change. https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/946597
